# Objective C interface generated header can't be imported in other header

Tags: objective-c, swift, bridging

I am not an Obj C pro, but I should write some code in Objective C and bridge a Swift code to it.
I success in importing the Generated Header to the .m file:

```
#import "<my_module>-Swift.h"
```

But when I try importing the same header to the .h file it throws this error:
[image]

BTW, I only want to add a public variable that instances from a Swift class to a specific obj c class. I've tried to put these lines at the .h and .m files:

```
@property (nonatomic, readwrite, strong) Card *card;
```

What should I do?

Comment: Just write `@class Card;`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, since all you need to do is declare a property of type `Card*`, you don't actually need to import the header—you can just **forward-declare** the class with `@class Card;` before using it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to reference a Swift class in an Objective-C header, you cannot `#import` the `*-Swift.h` file, but should rather use a forward declaration as described in https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html, see the section titled Referencing a Swift Class or Protocol in an Objective-C Header.  This is basically what @jtbandes is suggesting in the comment.

One gotcha here: the Swift class you want to use in Objective-C must extend the NSObject class, directly or indirectly.